# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints with Charts LineChartView

Tags: swift, macos, charts, ios-charts

I'm using LineChartView from [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in an osx app and I add it as follows to my view:

```
let lineChartView = LineChartView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
let ys1 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return sin(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141 * 1.5) }
let ys2 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return cos(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141) }

let yse1 = ys1.enumerate().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
let yse2 = ys2.enumerate().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }

let data = LineChartData()
let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "Hello")
ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.redColor()]
data.addDataSet(ds1)

let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse2, label: "World")
ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blueColor()]
data.addDataSet(ds2)
lineChartView.data = data

lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.whiteColor()

lineChartView.descriptionText = "Linechart Demo"
lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .Linear)
lineChartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
self.view.addSubview(lineChartView)
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: inspectorView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: inspectorView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inspectorView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```

Whenever `lineChartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is false the chart is not drawn. If I set it to `true` the chart is drawn but the runtime says it could not satisfy all constraints.

I also do the same with a standard `NSButton` for which  `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` works as expected

Why isn't it working for LineChartView and what needs to be changed?

**UPDATE:** as was pointed out in the comments: Adding height and width constraints solved the problem

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should be set to false. You constraints are not satisfactory.

Comment: If I remove the constraints and set it to false it doesn't show either.

Comment: Add height and width constraints also and remove hard coded frame size at allocation of `LineChartView `. Just pass `NSRect()`

Comment: Thank you: That was the solution